# Choosing the correct sentence

Tags: american-english, infinitives

Which one of these sounds correct (American English)? Is there a better way of saying this?

1. I was not sober enough for you **not to** notice I'd been drinking.
2. I was not sober enough for you **to not** notice I'd been drinking.

Comment: It actually does... thank you. Both "not to" and "to not" are acceptable these days, I get it. Now I wonder if this sentence sounds natural

Comment: @IloveRDJ The double negative makes it a little convoluted. How about "I was too inebriated for you not to notice..." or "I wasn't sober enough to hide that I'd been drinking..." or "From my behavior, you must've known I'd had a few too many."

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: I think you should think about the circularity of the idea itself as you express.  You are trying to say that “I’d drunk too much for it not to be obvious to you.”.   This is a much simpler way of putting it.

Comment: Is your audience over 40?

Comment: @phoog there's no audience, it's just my curiosity begging to be satisfied :) being a non-native english speaker sucks... sometimes you find yourself looking at a sentence, you know it's correct from a grammatical and lexical point of view but does it sound natural?

Comment: @Tuffy it truly is a better and simpler way of saying that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IloveRDJ You’re most welcome.

Comment: @JasonBassford the practical value of your suggestion can't be overstated. Thanks!